# News Module is Not Appearing in Typo3 Web Menu

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-news, typo3-12.x

I installed the news extension v11.2.0 on Typo3 v12.4.7 using composer. The extension is active. However, the news module is not appearing on the Web Typo3 menu. I expected to the news module to appear there as pointed out in:

https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.2/en-us/QuickStart/CreateRecords.html#quicknewsrecords

Note that I also installed Pizpalue template extension v15.2.0.

Thank you.

Comment: The backend module has moved to a separate extension with v10.0: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.2/en-us/Misc/Changelog/10-0-0.html#extract-backend-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BE module of the `ext:news` has been extracted into a dedicated, payed extension `ext:news_administration` since `ext:news v10`.

That's also stated in the extension changelog: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.2/en-us/Misc/Changelog/10-0-0.html#extract-backend-module

It seems, that the documentation in the subsection does not really cover this.

If you want to continue using the BE module for administrating news, you need to purchase the add-on extension, see: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.2/en-us/Addons/NewsAdministration/Index.html.

Otherwise, you can use TYPO3 core ways to manage these records. Use the "list" module for it on the folders where you have news records or want to create news records. To create new news, you can use "Create" function on that page, select a news record as type and than edit them. The "news" items are shown as a "news" list table along with other record types.

**edit 1**

Added changelog entry notice based on comment from Chris.